# Combining Two Data Fames with Different Row/Col Names Together

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this data frame:

```
dtMatrix <- structure(list(category = c("Opponent", "Opponent", "Opponent", 
"Opponent", "P1", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P2", "Opponent", "Opponent", 
"P1"), Event = c("Good Pass", "Good Pass", "Good Pass", "Turnover", 
"Good Pass", "Good Pass", "Good Pass", "Good Pass", "Good Pass", 
"Intercepted Pass", "Bad Pass", "Good Pass"), Receiver = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, "P2", "P3", "P4", "P5", "P1", NA, NA, "P2")), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

With this, I created a matrix

```
goodMatrix <- dtMatrix %>%
  filter(Event == 'Good Pass' & !is.na(Receiver)) %>%
  dplyr::count(category, Receiver) %>%
  tidyr::complete(category = dfList, Receiver = dfList, fill = list(n = 0)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Receiver, values_from = n) %>%
  column_to_rownames('category')
```

This `goodMatrix` stores the combinations of good passes between P1-P5. In the `dtMatrix`, it also has other values in the `Event` column such as turnover/intercepted pass, and also accounts for the opponent. I would like to create a similar matrix as `goodMatrix` but for the events and opponent previously mentioned.

`countTypes <- dtMatrix %>% dplyr::count(category, Event)` Grabs all the counts of the events based on the category column. With that, I then did:

```
secondMatrix <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = length(unique(countTypes$Event)), nrow = length(unique(countTypes$category))))
rownames(secondMatrix) <- unique(countTypes$category)
colnames(secondMatrix) <- unique(countTypes$Event)
secondMatrix

test <- merge(goodMatrix, secondMatrix, by = "row.names")
```

To try and combine the two separate matrices together.

```
anotherMatrix <- dtMatrix %>% 
  dplyr::count(category, Event) %>% 
  tidyr::complete(category = dfList, Event = dfList, fill = list(n = 0)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Event, values_from = n) %>%
  column_to_rownames('category')
```

This also adds them into one, but does not keep the values from `dtMatrix` and instead resets them to 0.

My expected result should look as such:

```
expectedOutput <- structure(list(P1 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), P2 = c(2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), P3 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), P4 = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), P5 = c(0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0), `Good Pass` = c(2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 3), `Bad Pass` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1), `Intercepted Pass` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), Turnover = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1)), row.names = c("P1", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P5", 
"Opponent"), class = "data.frame")
```

And `anotherMatrix` does half of this, while `dtMatrix` does the other half, but I am struggling on merging them into what I would like my result to be.

**Edit**

```
newTest <- test[,-1]
rownames(newTest) <- test[,1]
newTry <- merge(anotherMatrix, newTest, by = "row.names")
```

Just as an extra attempted method - this also gets close to my expected output, but does not include the opponent row, and also doubles every column.

```
dfList <- c("P1", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P5")
```

**Edit 2**

A quick follow up on combining 2 DF's with different row/col lengths, how would I go about combining `passesComb` + `copyComb` into `gamesComb`:

```
passesComb <- structure(list(P1_Good = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), P2_Good = c(2, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2), P3_Good = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), P4_Good = c(0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), P5_Good = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1), P1_Bad = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), P2_Bad = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), P3_Bad = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), P4_Bad = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), P5_Bad = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `Bad Pass` = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1), `Good Pass` = c(2, 
2, 1, 1, 0, 3, 6), `Intercepted Pass` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0
), Turnover = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), totalEvents = c(2, 2, 2, 
1, 0, 6, 7)), row.names = c("P1", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P5", "Opponent", 
"VT"), class = "data.frame")
```

and

```
copyComb <- structure(list(P1_Good = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), P2_Good = c(2, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 2), P4_Good = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), P5_Good = c(0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 1), P1_Bad = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), P2_Bad = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), P3_Bad = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), P4_Bad = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1), P5_Bad = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `Bad Pass` = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1), `Good Pass` = c(2, 2, 1, 0, 3, 6), `Intercepted Pass` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0), Turnover = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), totalEvents = c(2, 
2, 1, 0, 6, 7)), row.names = c("P1", "P2", "P4", "P5", "Opponent", 
"VT"), class = "data.frame")
```

`copyComb` is the same as `passesComb` just with row/column 3 removed. I tried adapting from the code for the original answer.

```
gamesComb <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = ifelse(nrow(passesComb) >= nrow(copyComb), nrow(passesComb),nrow(copyComb)),
                               ncol = ifelse(ncol(passesComb) >= ncol(copyComb), ncol(passesComb),ncol(copyComb))))
                        
gamesComb[row.names(ifelse(nrow(passesComb) >= nrow(copyComb), passesComb, copyComb)),
                           colnames(ifelse(ncol(passesComb) >= ncol(copyComb), passesComb, copyComb))] <- passesComb
```

but this only creates a 7x15 df and doesn't add the row/column names for some reason, in addition to not adding the cell values.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that part. Just put it in as an edit at the bottom @akrun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the intention is to update 'anotherMatrix' with `goodMatrix`, use the `row.names` and `colnames` from 'goodMatrix' to subset the 'anotherMatrix' and assign the 'goodMatrix' to 'anotherMatrix'

```
anotherMatrix[row.names(goodMatrix), colnames(goodMatrix)] <- goodMatrix
```

Then, we just replace the `NA` with 0

```
anotherMatrix[is.na(anotherMatrix)] <- 0
```

-checking with 'expectedOutput

```
> identical(expectedOutput, anotherMatrix[names(expectedOutput)])
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks! I just added an edit about combining two new DF's based on what you wrote and it didn't quite do what I was expecting. Would you be able to help with where I went wrong in the edit?

Comment: @samrizz4 I find the `gamesComb` you constructed doesn't have the same column name/row name as in `passesComb` or the other one

Comment: Yes, I tried using this line ```gamesComb <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = ifelse(nrow(passesComb) >= nrow(copyComb), nrow(passesComb),nrow(copyComb)),ncol = ifelse(ncol(passesComb) >= ncol(copyComb), ncol(passesComb),ncol(copyComb))))``` to get the same dim of whichever ```passesComb```7x15 & ```copyComb```6x14 is bigger,so ```gamesComb```turns into 7x15 but isn't adding the names. I am trying to add ```passesComb``` and ```copyComb``` into ```gamesComb```,where I would be adding each cell in the 2 DFs that has the same row/col name together, and similar to my OP, this has different dim sizes.