# Adding 2 DF's of Different Sizes Together

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two DF's:

```
passesComb <- structure(list(P1_Good = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), P2_Good = c(2, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2), P3_Good = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), P4_Good = c(0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), P5_Good = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1), P1_Bad = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), P2_Bad = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), P3_Bad = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), P4_Bad = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), P5_Bad = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `Bad Pass` = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1), `Good Pass` = c(2, 
2, 1, 1, 0, 3, 6), `Intercepted Pass` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0
), Turnover = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), totalEvents = c(2, 2, 2, 
1, 0, 6, 7)), row.names = c("P1", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P5", "Opponent", 
"VT"), class = "data.frame")
```

of size 7x15, and

```
copyComb <- structure(list(P1_Good = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), P2_Good = c(2, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 2), P4_Good = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), P5_Good = c(0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 1), P1_Bad = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), P2_Bad = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), P3_Bad = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), P4_Bad = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), P5_Bad = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `Bad Pass` = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0), `Good Pass` = c(2, 1, 1, 0, 3, 4), `Intercepted Pass` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0), Turnover = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), totalEvents = c(2, 
1, 1, 0, 6, 4)), row.names = c("P1", "P2", "P4", "P5", "Opponent", 
"VT"), class = "data.frame")
```

or simply,

```
copyComb <- passesComb
copyComb <- copyComb[-3,-3]
#Updating specific cells since [3,3] is removed
copyComb[2,11] <- 1
copyComb[2,14] <- 1
copyComb[6,8] <- 0
copyComb[6,3] <- 0
copyComb[6,10] <- 0
copyComb[6,11] <- 4
copyComb[6,14] <- 4
#This now equals the copyComb from dput() above
```

of size 6x14.

I am trying to combine/add these two df's together based on matching row/column names. I tried to achieve this using the code from the answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69491160/combining-two-data-fames-with-different-row-col-names-together)

```
gamesComb <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = ifelse(nrow(passesComb) >= nrow(copyComb), nrow(passesComb),nrow(copyComb)),
                               ncol = ifelse(ncol(passesComb) >= ncol(copyComb), ncol(passesComb),ncol(copyComb))))
                        
gamesComb[row.names(ifelse(nrow(passesComb) >= nrow(copyComb), passesComb, copyComb)),
                           colnames(ifelse(ncol(passesComb) >= ncol(copyComb), passesComb, copyComb))] <- passesComb
```

Here, I create a df, `gamesComb` and set the dimensions of whichever `passesComb` or `copyComb` is bigger. It does create a 7x15 df, but doesn't add the row/col names.

I also am trying to then add the 2 df's together based on the cell value if they have the same row/col name (same as in the post link above), i.e. `passesComb["P2","P1_Good"]` = 1 and `copyComb["P2","P1_Good"]` = 1, so `gamesComb["P2","P1_Good"]` should = 2, and same for all similar row/col names.

So the final result look like:

```
expectedOutput <- structure(list(P1_Good = c(0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2), P2_Good = c(4, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4), P3_Good = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), P4_Good = c(0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), P5_Good = c(0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2), P1_Bad = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), P2_Bad = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), P3_Bad = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), P4_Bad = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), P5_Bad = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `Bad Pass` = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1), `Good Pass` = c(4, 
3, 1, 2, 0, 6, 10), `Intercepted Pass` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 
0), Turnover = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0), totalEvents = c(4, 3, 
2, 2, 0, 12, 11)), row.names = c("P1", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P5", 
"Opponent", "VT"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to stack them and then sum by rowname groups.

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(tibble)

out <- 
  rownames_to_column(passesComb) %>% 
    bind_rows(rownames_to_column(copyComb)) %>% 
    # bind_rows(rownames_to_column(third_table)) %>% if you want to add another
    select(rowname, names(passesComb)) %>% 
    group_by(rowname) %>% 
    summarise(across(everything(), sum, na.rm = T)) %>% 
    slice(match(rownames(passesComb), rowname)) %>% 
    column_to_rownames('rowname')
  
all.equal(out, expectedOutput)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Adding ```copyComb``` again and replacing it with where you had ```third_table```, why does running that code then make ```out``` into a 19x16 instead of a 7x15 which it should be (and is without the 3rd table)?

Comment: You need to add a pipe at the end of that line too, forgot to add that part

Comment: Just caught that as well and was about to comment that. Thanks!

Comment: Also, just to clarify, the first ```rownames_to_column()``` df is the one that has the biggest dimensions, and then same with the df in ```select()``` and ```slice()```, correct? I just tested it out and made an 8x17 df, and replaced it where ```passesComb``` went and it worked (changing dim of ```out``` to 8x17), but replacing it where ```copyComb``` was yields the dim of the smaller df (```passesComb``` 7x15). Am I understanding the syntax properly? I'd just like to make sure for future use.

Comment: The code should output a table with same dimensions as `passesComb`, or anything else you replace `passesComb` with in both the `select` (ensures same columns) and `slice` (ensures same rows and row order). But, the thing you put there doesn't need to have the largest dimensions among all the tables, it could be smaller too.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a dplyr/tidyr approach where I reshape each table into a long format, then join them, sum, and pivot wider again.

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr)
lengthen <- function(df) { df %>% rownames_to_column(var = "row") %>% pivot_longer(-row)}

full_join(lengthen(passesComb), lengthen(copyComb), by = c("row", "name")) %>%
  mutate(new_val = coalesce(value.x, 0) + coalesce(value.y, 0)) %>%
  select(-starts_with("value")) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name,values_from = new_val)
```

Comment: If I wanted to add a third table (instead of ```passesComb``` + ```copyComb``` in my OP) and wanted to do ```passesComb```+```copyComb```+```copyComb```, would that look like ```full_join(lengthen(passesComb), lengthen(copyComb), lengthen(copyComb), by = c("row", "name")) %>% mutate(new_val = coalesce(value.x, 0) + coalesce(value.y, 0)) %>% select(-starts_with("value")) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = name,values_from = new_val)```, where I add another ```lengthen(copyComb)``` after the first? Is there an easier way to add ```n``` amount of tables together instead of just 2?

Comment: No, I think you'd use something like `lengthen(passesComb) %>% full_join( lengthen(copyComb), by = c("row", "name")) %>% full_join( lengthen(thirdComb), by = c("row", "name")) %>% ...`